# Ordering a results set with pagination using will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I'm using [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) for pagination in a Rails 3 site. I'd like to be able to click on the table headers (e.g. "name", "created at") for each of the output fields and have the results ordered on that field. It would also be nice to be able to click again for reverse ordering. Is there something that works well with will_paginate for ordering? Can I do this just using will_paginate?

The table format I'm using is pretty generic:

```
<%= will_paginate %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
    </tr>   
    <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= shop.id %></td>
        <td><%= shop.name %></td>
        <td><%= shop.updated_at.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M ") %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find all you expect illustrated here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
gem "meta_search"
```

with will_paginate

[Github project site](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

[Railscasct #251 MetaWhere & MetaSearch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/251-metawhere-metasearch)

Index controller example

```
@search =  Customer.search(params[:search])
@customer = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 50)
```

and view example

```
<th><%= sort_link @search, :name%></th>
<th><%= sort_link @search, :surname %></th>
<th><%= sort_link @search, :address %></th>
```

Answer (score -2):

**Alternatives:**

**1) Using powerful jquery plugin:**

Sorting and pagination became simple with jquery plugin.

There is a powerful jquery plugin [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

More for [jQuery Tablesorter: Pagination and Sorting made simple](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8797/jquery-tablesorter-pagination-and-sorting-made-simple).

**2) Sortable Table Columns:**

If you want sorting without jquery plugin then you will get everything you want [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns).
The above method adds the ability to sort table columns in ascending or descending order by clicking the header.

Comment: You can do sorting with `will_paginate`. If you use just jquery for sorting a table you're only sorting the values you already have in the table and not the, potentially thousands of, values you might have in the database.

Comment: Is that? I think that `will_paginate` gem itself can't do..However `jquery-rails` can. Modified to the point. See my updated answer with alternatives.

Comment: Also what is the difference between values you have or values you might have? In the end, the `might have` will become `have`.

Comment: If you have a table with 10 entries in it that are the first 10 of a thousand entries sorted by date then resorting them by name is very different to getting the first 10 entries sorted by name.